# Can I really get scrod?

Tags: verbs, tenses

There's a family of jokes where Person A asks where he can "get scrod" (meaning the fish), and Person B interprets "scrod" as being some obscure conjugation of the verb "to screw".

Has "scrod" ever actully been used as a conjugation of "to screw"?

Comment: Erm...is this a troll?

Comment: @Cascabel -- Ooh! You almost caught me there!

Comment: @HotLicks Only if you were in the net I cast for Random under the bridge...

Comment: SCROD = Select Catch Received on Deck/the Day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* (subscription required) shows these historical forms for the verb *screw*:

> Forms:  15– screw, 16 screue, 16 screwe, 16 scrud (past tense and past participle), 16–17 scrue, 16–17 skrew, 16–17 skrue.

So, the closest to *scrod* seems to be *scrud* used in the 16th century.

Comment: I wonder though whether "scrud" was supposed to be pronounced like "screwd" (i.e. to rhyme with "rude" rather than with "mud").

Comment: @sumelic Sounds right to me. Particularly looking at the next entry, "scrue".